# Export original media files from wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to export the image media files from a WordPress blog but I'm not able to find any option or a plugin that can solve this issue.

I need to have all the media files, images and audio files, in a zip with the original name so I can rebuild the blog posts entirely in separate html pages.

Comment: Wordpress is installed in a cloud machine? and you do you have access to it?

Comment: In your WordPress dashboard, under Tools you have an Export option. You can export all content that way, although it exports it as an XML file, which would allow you to upload the file to another fresh copy of WordPress and if you select the option to import media it should copy over the media files to the new installation.

Comment: It's installed using Wordpress.com

Comment: @JoseGuerra I know, thanks. But it doesn't export the files in a zip. I need them only in this way and I don't have to create another wordpress blog!

Comment: Consider searching for WordPress backup in the plugins repository or in your WordPress dashboard, go to add plugins and search for WordPress backup. I haven't used these in a while but there are a few that will backup your blog, including your media and give you a download link as a zip, rar or tar or whatever other formats they offer.